# connecting to and using the same database in MongoDB python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I tried to connect to MongoDb server remotely using python pymongo, but when I tried to display documents from collection I got error message as

> "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: not authorized on pt to execute command { find: "devices", filter: {} }" .

Also when I tried get single record from mongo, it will not display the record details instead it will display as

> "pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x000001E883A14F98".

Mongo Server Details: Host: Someth-pt-ved-01
                      user: uname
                      pwd: mypass
                      authenticationDatabase: pt
                      collection: devices

---

My python code for connection is:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
uri = "mongodb://uname:mypass@Someth-pt-ved-01:27017"
client = MongoClient(uri)
db = client.pt
collection = db.devices
#to get single record details
cursor = collection.find({'ID': 1490660})
print(cursor)
#to get all documents from collection-devices
for document in cursor:
    print(document)
```

Note; I am working on Windows 10.

Comment: It means that the user is "not authorised" just like the error says. Either the user lacks the required permissions or you have the wrong database namespace. Check that you actually have a `read` or `readWrite` assigned to the user for the selected database. Full information is available on ["Built In Roles"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/). Note that the most common mistake is something like `dbAdmin` does not actually have permission to query collections.

Comment: I am capable to do any read write update delete operations on same db with command line.

Comment: Edit your question to show "connecting to and using the same database" with something else then. If the credentials are good then you should be able to connect to the same database and issue the query without error. But what I am saying is that you are either connecting to a "different" database, or the user still lacks the privilege and the action would be denied for the same reason. Therefore more likely doing something different than having discovered an actual bug. The burden on proof in on you. Show something that proves your case, or realize the mistake in the process of doing that.

Comment: How can i check my(user) built in role in MongoDB? i tried db.getRoles()... got below error:                                                    [thread1] Error: not authorized on pt to execute command { rolesInfo: 1.0 } :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
DB.prototype.getRoles@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1671:1

Comment: [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45114519/edit) to show you can connect as you claim or retract your claim and correct your credentials in the way they were created. This is not a chat room. You have already been told where to look and there is plenty of documentation on the subject.